# why object in collection of System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator cannot be changed

Tags: c#, linq

I use Linq to select some data and the returned type is WhereSelectListIterator. I find that object in WhereSelectListIterator cannot be modified, e.g., set to null or update any property of that value. Is it by design? How to make that possible?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace linqtest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var project = new Project()
            {
                Sections = new List<Section>()
                {
                    new Section()
                    {
                        OutDated = new char[2]{'a','d'}

                    },
                    new Section()
                    {
                        OutDated = new char[2]{'a','d'}

                    },
                    new Section()
                    {
                        OutDated = new char[2]{'a','d'}

                    }
                }
            };


            var dates = project.Sections.Select(t=>(new MyString(t.OutDated)));
            Console.Write(dates.ElementAt(0).Description);
            dates.ElementAt(0).Description = "123";
            Console.Write(dates.ElementAt(0).Description);
            Console.Read();

        }
    }


    class MyString
    {
        public MyString(char[] abc)
        {
                Description = new string(abc).Substring(1);
        }
        public string Description { set; get; }
    }
    class Project
    {
        public IEnumerable<Section> Sections;
    }
    internal class Section
    {
        public char[] OutDated;

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: You need to post a good code example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. It's not really clear what you are trying to do here. Explain in detail what you've tried, what happens when you try it, and how that's different from what you wanted. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DavidG please see the code sample

Comment: @PeterDuniho please see the code sample

Comment: @Bargitta `AddYears` *never* updates any variable. It returns a *new* `DateTime` value, which you can then store somewhere. Just try it: `var x = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1); x.AddYears(4);`, and then see what value `x` then has.

Comment: @Bargitta Your updated question looks like a fair question to me. You *can* update `Description`, but every time you iterate over `dates`, you get a brand new object, because that's just how `Select` works. Print out `dates.ElementAt(0) == dates.ElementAt(0)`, and you'll see `false`. So when you set `dates.ElementAt(0).Description`, and then read `dates.ElementAt(0).Description`, you don't read it from the same object you just set it on. (I'd expand and post this as an answer, but that's not possible as long as the question is closed.)

Comment: Thanks @hvd, i think i understand your point now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ acts like using the `yield` operator on a collection. If you modify the collection, it invalidates the iterator.

To workaround this, consider converting to a concrete class rather than working with the `IEnumerable<T>` by calling `ToArray()` or `ToList()` on the `IEnumerable<T>`.